# How do I get the number of the current week?

Tags: java, android

I want to write a simple app, which opens a website in a folder named with the current week number.
So for example:

http://www.website.de/content/35/index.html

thats the basic structure.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: [RTFM](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#WEEK_OF_YEAR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you get the current week number:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int week = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)
```

This is how you open a website:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.website.de/content/"+week+"/index.html"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 5):

Import `java.util.Calendar` and implement:

```
public static int getWeek() {
    return Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use calender for that like this -

```
Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
Log.d("Current Week:" + calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
```

for more details[java.util.Calender](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#WEEK_OF_YEAR)

Comment: Thanks! I will give that a try !!